# MVC5 radiobutton value error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I am a bit new to MVC having begun migrating from web forms so bear with me please.

I have a radio button group for gender defined as;

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "col-xs-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "form-control", value= Gender.Male})<span>Male</span>
                @*<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/> Male*@
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "form-control", value = Gender.Female }) <span>Female</span >
                @*<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female*@
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where Gender is an enum defined in another project, but the viewmodel class uses that enum.

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Gender")]
 public DomainClasses.Enums.Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

No matter what I seem to try to get this right I get the following validation error.

> The value '{ class = form-control, value = Male }' is not valid for Gender.

**UPDATE:**

The original look prior to submitting this was

[image]

But upon changing to the suggested methods, why is the look now this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at *this* image

[image]

This image shows that, there is no **overload** for accepting **second** parameter as **Html Attributes**,So you need to write like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "col-xs-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Male , new { @class = "form-control" })<span>Male</span>
                @*<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/> Male*@
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, Gender.Female,  new { @class = "form-control" }) <span>Female</span >
                @*<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female*@
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this overload, you are passing the second parameter as the **value** for the **RadioButton**

Comment: Shouldn't the second parameter just be the desired enum item, rather than trying to assign to 'value'?

Comment: @ChrisDavis sorry, I cut from the code and put it.Thanks

Comment: Please see updated post, your suggested changes made the look wrong, why did that happen?

Comment: @dinotom It is the styles issue,I don't see your styles,Try to Inspect in browser

Comment: @dinotom because the RadioButton itself doesn't create text,it is the span's issue,see the styles of the spans